# graphQL Query: getting error "Expected value of type ..., found ..."

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

Suppose I have the following object types:

```
    type Price {
        currency: Currency!,
        amount: Float!
    }

    type Attribute {
        displayValue: String,
        value: String,
        id: String!
    }

    type AttributeSet {
        id: String!,
        name: String,
        type: String,
        items: [Attribute]
    }

    type Product {
        id: String!,
        name: String!,
        inStock: Boolean,
        gallery: [String],
        description: String!,
        category: String!,
        attributes: [AttributeSet]
        prices: [Price!]!,
        brand: String!
    }

    type Category {
        name: String,
        products: [Product]!
    }

    type Currency {
        label: String!,
        symbol: String!
    }

    input CategoryInput {
        title: String!
    }

    type Query {
        categories: [Category],
        category(input: CategoryInput): Category,
        product(id: String!): Product,
        currencies: [Currency]
    }
```

And these are the Types for `Category`:

```
export enum Category {
    all = 'all',
    clothes = 'clothes',
    tech = 'tech'
};
```

In graphQL Playground, I am trying to make a query to exhibit all the names and products/id of the elements with the category `all`. Here's my attempt:

```
{
  category(input: "all") {
    name
    products {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error message:

```
"message": "Expected value of type \"CategoryInput\", found \"all\".",
```

I need help trying to understand what went wrong since `all` is a valid type. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well your schema says `category(input: CategoryInput): Category`, where `CategoryInput` is an object with a `title` property. That's not what you want? Where in your schema is the enum declared?

Comment: Yes, now I see that it is confusing. What should I put in the "input" field then?

Comment: A [GraphQL enum type](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#enumeration-types)

Comment: Just need an example of a valid query so I can visualize it

Comment: The problem is not (only) with the query. You need to fix the *schema* first

Comment: by fixing you mean making an enum for CategoryInput?

Comment: Yes, or rather, *instead* of `CategoryInput`

Comment: The thing is: when I make a query without any input as a parameter, the query works as if using the standard value for the input.

Comment: There is no standard value for the input? At least not in your schema?

Comment: I found a resolver for the Category, so I am going to add it to the question. If you could take a look

Comment: Just found my mistake, Bergi. I will post it. Thanks for your time and patience

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found my mistake

`CategoryInput` is of type

```
input CategoryInput {
        title: String!
    }
```

So a proper query would be:

```
{
  category(input: { title: "all" }) {
    name
    products {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But that's not an enum? You can pass *any* string as the title?